# Why doesn't the VSCode debugger work with default launch.json settings in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-code

The debugging doesn't work at all. When running 'dotnet run' from an external terminal, the app runs with no problems(builds and runs properly). But when going to the "Run" tab in the "Activity Bar" and launching the ".NET Core Launch (console)" option, nothing happens. It doesn't run the program at all. It is like it hangs in a infinite loop. No breakpoints hit, not even the Main method is executed(tested with my application and with a "Hello World" example). I tried changing the "console" in launch.json to "integratedTerminal", "externalTerminal" and "internalConsole". None work. "ExternalTerminal" goes further then the others, but still nothing show. No print statements show, no cursor movement, no action. Just hangs and nothing. With this option, when i stop the debugger from the vscode itself, it does print "Click any key to continue...". In the end i tried with the ".NET Core Attach", but no success there too. I need to debug my application, because it's essential for my work. Please, I can use some assistance. Haven't had this problem before.

Notes:

```
I) I haven't tested with other languages
II) Creating a new project and debugging it doesn't fix the issue. It still persists with default debug settings and default launch.json file.
III) When using "console": "externalTerminal" in launch.json, the settings option "Terminal › External: Linux Exec" is set to "konsole". Tried with "gnome-terminal", but no success.
```

My Configuration:

```
VSCode Version: 1.47.3
OS Version: Arch Linux (fully updated; date: 12 AUG 2020)
DE: KDE V.5.73.0
Terminal: Konsole
```

Steps to Reproduce:

```
I) Open VSCode(either from "Application" or with "code ." in terminal)
II) Promts you for assets for debugging and such, to which you answer "Yes"
III) Go to "Run" section to debug
IV) Debug using ".NET Core Launch (console)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arch Linux package was broken at the time of posting this. Downloading the official package from Microsoft's site solved the issue. Better to use the officia

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead on your launch.json

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```